# laravel 5 Find issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$account = Account::Find(1);
```

I use this code to get row in table which id is 1 when I return the value It become `{"id":1,"0":1,"username":"Jack","1":"Jack","email":"jack@email.com","2":"email":"jack@email.com" }` although I don't have attributes ("0","1","2")

Account is Eloquent model

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `attributes ("0","1","2")`?

Comment: when I return object as json it add attributes not in database table

Comment: Is this the behaviour with all of your models?

Comment: Try using `findOrFail()`

Answer (score 0):

`find()` returns instanse by `ID`. To get `username`, just use `$account->username`, to get `email`, use `$account->email` etc.

`find()` manual:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: I want to return object data in json

Comment: Oh. Then you can use `visible` array to return only data that you need: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

Comment: Also, what method/function do you use to encode object to JSON?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please upvote and choose it as best answer.